# How do I resolve Unhandled Exception Error in Wildfly?

Tags: java, wildfly-10

I've been tasked with finding a solution to a bug that we have been seeing for ~1.5 years off and on since Dec '17 but started happening WAY more in Dec '18.  We are using Wildfly 10.1 Final.  When I check the logs in Wildfly, I see this:

> 2019-05-05 00:19:32,980 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3)
>
> > UT005023: Exception handling request to /SMARxT-02.001/Usage/Create: >org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: RESTEASY00 3770: Response is committed, can't handle exception at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispa>tcher.java:174)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispat>cher.java:478)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.ja>va:422)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.ja>va:209)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(>ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpS>ervletDispatcher.java:56)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpS>ervletDispatcher.java:51)
> >     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java>:85)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleReques>t(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletD>ispatchingHandler.java:36)
> >     at
> >     org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.han>dleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.j>ava:43)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handle>Request(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handle>Request(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.j>ava:43)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(A>uthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(Ab>stractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler>.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handle>Request(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(A>uthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handl>eRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(Notif>icationReceiverHandler.java:50)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handl>eRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.j>ava:43)
> >     at
> >     org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleReque>st(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.j>ava:43)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.j>ava:43)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(Servlet>InitialHandler.java:292)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialH>andler.java:81)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandl>er.java:138)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandl>er.java:135)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(Servle>tRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoa>derSetupAction.java:43)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSet>upActionWrapper.java:44)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSet>upActionWrapper.java:44)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSet>upActionWrapper.java:44)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSet>upActionWrapper.java:44)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSet>upActionWrapper.java:44)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletIni>tialHandler.java:272)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialH>andler.java:81)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletIni>tialHandler.java:104)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
> >     at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:114>9)
> >     at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:62>4)
> >     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) : Caused by:
> >     javax.json.JsonException: I/O error while closing JsonGenerator at
> >     org.glassfish.json.JsonGeneratorImpl.close(JsonGeneratorImpl.java:587)
> >     at org.glassfish.json.JsonWriterImpl.close(JsonWriterImpl.java:126) at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jsonp.JsonObjectProvider.writeTo(JsonObj>ectProvider.java:73)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jsonp.JsonObjectProvider.writeTo(JsonObj>ectProvider.java:25)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo>(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:131)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(S>erverWriterInterceptorContext.java:60)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed>(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:120)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(Di>gitalSigningInterceptor.java:145)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed>(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:124)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.arou>ndWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed>(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:124)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerRespons>eWriter.java:98)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispat>cher.java:473)
> >     ... 45 more Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException at
> >     io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedStreamSinkChannel.safeToSend>(AbstractFramedStreamSinkChannel.java:458)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedStreamSinkChannel.write(Abst>ractFramedStreamSinkChannel.java:412)
> >     at org.xnio.channels.Channels.writeFinalBasic(Channels.java:961) at
> >     io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal>(AbstractFramedStreamSinkChannel.java:475)
> >     at
> >     org.xnio.conduits.StreamSinkChannelWrappingConduit.writeFinal(StreamSinkChann>elWrappingConduit.java:66)
> >     at
> >     org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChanne>l.java:104)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamS>inkChannel.java:195)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpSer>verExchange.java:2007)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletO>utputStreamImpl.java:561)
> >     at
> >     io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImp>l.java:596)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$Deferred>OutputStream.close(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:58)
> >     at
> >     org.jboss.resteasy.util.CommitHeaderOutputStream.close(CommitHeaderOutputStre>am.java:87)
> >     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320) at
> >     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149) at
> >     java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233) at
> >     org.glassfish.json.JsonGeneratorImpl.close(JsonGeneratorImpl.java:585)
> >     ... 57 more

If I understand this correctly, Wildfly is throwing an unhandled exception error due to the JsonGenerator not being closed properly, which is caused by a ClosedChannelException.  I have attempted to correlate these timestamps with our logs from aws to see the network traffic and I cannot find a definitive pattern.  Does anyone have any insight as to what/where I should be looking to further troubleshoot this?  Apologies if I left anything out.  Im still learning how wildfly works and I don't have admin rights but I should be able to provide any info that will help.  Thanks!

Comment: What about memory consumption of Wildfly's JVM? Is there any chance that your JSON payloads have grown enormously since Dec'17?

Comment: So our payloads havent gotten THAT much bigger, but after checking,  the JVM is using almost all of the memory allocated to it.  Our current thinking is that its running out of memory which causes the channel to close.  Im digging into the aws data now to confirm

Comment: Were you able to find out the root cause?